# Adding a project to an existing .net core 3.1 project in visual studio for mac

Tags: .net-core

I have an existing .net 3.1 functions app that I'm trying to add another project to.  The current structure shows

[image]

Next I right click on the topmost directory (with the EIQT-765) and then select Add -> New Project.  I select an xunit project template and add. I end up with this (noting that functions.test is at the root directory, and within the original

[image]

After a rebuild at the solution level (again, right click the topmost directory) I am able to add a simple assertion to the initially generated UnitTest1.cs file and right click on the file (in either place it shows in solution explorer) and run the test fine.

When I add some real test stuff that needs to use classes from the app I get a lot of "type or namespace not found errors"

[image]

As a freshman .net developer I've solved this in the past with adding a reference to the real project from the test project.  I did the same here, Right click on the topmost functions.test folder -> Add -> Reference -> Select the real project.
[image]

Not sure if it's relevant, but the test project now has a mono_crash.[string].json file, which doesn't seem good :D.

Next I add the Xunit package to the functions.test project. However, the solution will no longer build unless I add the Xunit package to the real project.

Finally, after all this I have the following error when trying to rebuild the solution
`Error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute (CS0579)`  which is where I'm currently stuck.

Is this the correct way to add a project to an existing one? Other projects I've worked on were set up as a solution first and I've never had this issue adding additional projects.  What do I need to do to fix this?

This issue https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4837 leads me to believe I need to rearrange my project structure but I'm just not sure how to do this with a .net project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the same issue in the github thread.  In order to fix this I carefully moved things around until I had a structure like this

```
/FunctionsApp
functionsapp.sln
/FunctionsApp/Functions <-- all the original work went in here, including the .csproj
```

I then had to manually update the functionsapp.sln with the new path.  Afterwards, I could follow the process of Add Project and Add Reference and my tests now run.